# JW Player source URL not being read/played

Tags: url, video, jwplayer

So when I use a url like so 
http://s46.auengine.com/videos/LsgJAxV.mp4?st=WHFb1jqsRQb7CzAmc_mp0A&e=1386052394 as the source for JW Player, it won't read/play it. However the url will be read/played on other html players. Is there any reason why this is happening? Is there there anything special I have to do to make JW Player read the url?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://animefang.com/js/jwplayer.js"></script>
<div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        file: "http://s46.auengine.com/videos/LsgJAxV.mp4?st=WHFb1jqsRQb7CzAmc_mp0A&amp;e=1386052394",
        image: "/uploads/myPoster.jpg"
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For JW6.

Under:

```
file: "http://s46.auengine.com/videos/LsgJAxV.mp4?st=WHFb1jqsRQb7CzAmc_mp0A&amp;e=1386052394",
```

Add:

```
type: "mp4",
```

If you are using JW5, it should be:

```
provider: "video",
```